# Websocket header to reject handshake

Tags: http, websocket

What is the way to reject a websocket handshake.
Based on the documentation to accept a handshake a response from the http server is sent like this

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
```

But if I want to reject the handshake for various reasons is it good to return HTTP code `403` or is there another way for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ANY* final (ie non-authorization, non-redirect) HTTP response code other than 101 will abort the handshake, so use whatever response code makes sense for your needs per normal HTTP semantics.

Per [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455):

> Any status code other than 101 indicates that the WebSocket handshake has not completed and that the semantics of HTTP still apply.
>
> ...
>
> If the |Sec-WebSocket-Accept| value does not match the expected value, if the header field is missing, or if the HTTP status code is not 101, the connection will not be established, and WebSocket frames will not be sent.
>
> ...
>
> Once the client's opening handshake has been sent, the client MUST wait for a response from the server before sending any further data. The client MUST validate the server's response as follows:
>
> 1. If the status code received from the server is not 101, the client handles the response per HTTP [RFC2616] procedures.  In particular, the client might perform authentication if it receives a 401 status code; the server might redirect the client using a 3xx status code (but clients are not required to follow them), etc.  Otherwise, proceed as follows.
>
> ...
>
> If the server's response does not conform to the requirements for the server's handshake as defined in this section and in Section 4.2.2, the client MUST _Fail the WebSocket Connection_.